# bxSlider pager: make an image instead of numbers

Tags: jquery, block, bxslider

I'm having problems only on iPad with the bxSlider.

Originally the numbers in the pager were "hidden" by using a `text-indent:-9999px` and `display:block;`, then having a `background-color` and `border-radius` to make a small circle instead of the number.

The problem is that `display:block` causes a huge iPad specific issue where it extends the page out. I've tried everything and have narrowed it down entirely to that single `display:block`. Remove that and it fixes the issue, but then you get the numbers showing as the `text-indent` not longer works.

Is there a solution to remove the numbers from the pager and replace them with an image? I have an image for the default and one for the active state but I can't find anyway of choosing to have a numberless pager without hiding the number.

Answer (score 0):

Replace background-color  with background of the image and it will work, if i have understand your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also apply `color:transparent;` on that text. and what about the use of `display: inline-block;` with `vertical-align: middle;`. If you want them to be centered you just have to apply a `text-align: center;` on a parent block of these pager links.